# Write a function with NumPy to calculate integral with a specific tolerance

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-integration

I want to write a custom function to integrate an expression (python or lambda function) numerically with a specific tolerance. I know with `scipy.integrate.quad` one can simply change the `epsabs` but I want to write the function myself using numpy.

From [this blogpost](https://helloacm.com/how-to-compute-numerical-integration-in-numpy-python/) I know the function:

```
def integrate(f, a, b, N):
    x = np.linspace(a+(b-a)/(2*N), b-(b-a)/(2*N), N)
    fx = f(x)
    area = np.sum(fx)*(b-a)/N
    return area
```

gives me the numerical integration with N segments. How can I write another function or extend this to take a `tol` input and increase N until the difference between the two subsequent calculations is smaller than the given tolerance?

Answer (score 2):

Using the function you have, one can start with a reasonable N, for example 5, and keep doubling the number until the required precision is reached.

```
def integrate_tol(f, a, b, tol):
    N = 5
    old_integral = integrate(f, a, b, N)
    while True:
        N *= 2
        new_integral = integrate(f, a, b, N)
        if np.abs(old_integral - new_integral) < tol:
            return (4*new_integral - old_integral)/3
        old_integral = new_integral
```

A simple test:

```
f = lambda x: np.exp(x)     
print(integrate_tol(f, -1, 1, 1e-9))
print(np.exp(1)-np.exp(-1))   # exact value for comparison
```

prints

```
2.3504023872876028
2.3504023872876028
```

There is no guarantee that the  error is indeed less than `tol` (but then again, `scipy.quad` does not guarantee that either).  In practice, the error will be much smaller than tol, because of the trick I used, called [Richardson extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation): the return value `(4*new_integral - old_integral)/3` is in general much more accurate than either new or old approximations themselves. (Explanation: since `integrate` uses the midpoint rule, each doubling of N reduces the error by the factor of about 4. So, taking the combination `4*new_integral - old_integral` nearly cancels out the residual error in both of those results.)

(Remark: in the while loop it's unadvisable to start with N=1; it probably will not be enough, and there's higher risk of stopping too early because of some numerical coincidence, e.g., the function being   zero in a bunch of places.)

Comment: Great job. I think we can also calculate the integral for some random Ns and then considering that the function of Int(N) asymptotes we can fit a S shaped function (e.g. erf) to estimate the correct N to get the correct tolerance. How do you think?

Comment: There is no numerical integration method that guarantees error bounds without some assumptions on the function (like derivative bounds). If error bounds are important, start by reading up on [numerical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration). Fitting `erf`, which has superexponential decay, makes no sense here.