# Python integration using both scipy and sympy

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I want to have a custom python function which:

1. Takes a mathematical expression `f(x)` , bounds of the integral `x1,x2` and desired tolerance `tol`
2. Uses `sympy.integrate(y, x)` to check if it has analytical/symbolic solution, if it does then returns the result using `sympy.integrate(y, (x,x1,x2).evalf())`
3. If it doesn't have an analytical solution out of the `sympy` then it uses `scipy.integrate.quad` or [other numerical functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033275/write-a-function-with-numpy-to-calculate-integral-with-a-specific-tolerance) to calculate the integral.

The reason is that with this method it will be probably faster and more accurate as a majority of mathematical expressions I'm working with, have analytical integrals.

But I have some issues

- first of all `scipy.integrate.quad` and `sympy.integrate` two very different forms of functions. scipy takes python `def y(x): return f(x)` or lambda `y=lambda x: f(x)` functions. But sympy takes mathematica expressions `y=f(x)` where `x` has been symbolized by `sympy.Symbol('x')`. I need to find a way to convert a sympy symbolic mathematical expression to python/lambda function or vise versa.
- my second issue is that sympy does not give any error when the expression doesn't have an analytical integral. it just prints the integral! (for this issue I posted a different question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039222/sympy-how-to-check-if-an-expression-has-analytical-solution))
- And last one I don't know how control the tolerance in sympy's `evalf()`. I think for `scipy.integrate.quad` one can control the tolerance with `epsabs` input?

I would appreciate if you could let me know if it is possible and how to do it.

Comment: **1.** *... way to convert a [sympy] expression to lambda*: [see `sympy.utilities.lambdify`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html). **2.** *...it just prints the integral!* I'm not sure what functionality you are talking about, but most likely it actually returns an expression (which is printed by the REPL). It may be possible to check if the resulting expression is an unsolved integral. **3.** There is no tolerance in sympy because it is analytic. You only need tolerance when numerically approximating something.

Comment: In summary: Yes it should be possible. Yet, the "how" is too broad a question and I have voted to close it as such.

Comment: @kazemakase Thanks for the comments, the closing flag is a bummer though :) 1. I will look into the [sympy.utilities.lambdify](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) that's a very important part of the solution 2. I don't know what REPL is. The functionality I want is that when the mathematical expression doesn't have any analytical solution in sympy it gives me an error instead of just printing the requested integral. 3. sympy doesn't have a tolerance but `evalf()` does and that's what I meant.

Comment: for 2 I posted [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039222/sympy-how-to-check-if-an-expression-has-analytical-solution).

Comment: **2.** REPL means "read-eval-print-loop" this is what you are working with if you type commands in the interpreter directly (opposed to writing a script). If you get an error there almost certainly is a way to retrieve it. Do you know about [Exception Handling](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions)? **3.** I misunderstood that point, sorry. I think [`feval` has an accuracy parameter](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html) but I have not used it.

Comment: @kazemakase thanks for the points 1. would you be so kind to see my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039222/sympy-how-to-check-if-an-expression-has-analytical-solution)? 2. I'm not sure how `read-eval-print-loop (REPL )` relates to my problem, but I did try to run the commands in python shell/terminal, instead of Jupyter, and got the same result with no errors. 3. The `try:` , `except` is exactly what I'm going to use as soon as I get some error out of `sympy.integrate`.